# Sending meaningless Addresses requests to a series of malicious IPs

Tags: malware, web-browser, ip, chrome, wireshark

i was testing somethings on browsers(It has nothing to do with what I am going to say) and accidentally i faced a case that when i browse meaningless addresses like `abc/` `signortest/` `word/` 
the request sent to ip addresses hosted on linode!(i attached wireshark capture), that some of those IPs was reported malicious.

and i receive two different answers from them .(pictures attached)

1. 4001
2. 503 Service Unavailable

the destination ips are listed on abuseipdb and virustotal DBs.
some of them are known as malicious requests, malwares, spams etc...
1- [AbuseIPDB_1](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/198.58.118.167)
2- [AbuseIPDB-2](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/45.33.2.79)
3- [AbuseIPDB_3](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/45.79.19.196)
4- [VirusTotal_1](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/ip-address/198.58.118.167/detection)
5- [VirusTotal_2](http://45.33.2.79)
6- [virusTotal_3](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/ip-address/45.79.19.196/detection)

i guess maybe it is malware on my computer but i didn't detect that with some general tools such as Malwarebytes.
how i can understand what's going on my computer? Or what else should I look for to know that i'm infected or not.

.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you are exactly doing, what you were expecting and what your question is. Please explain your problem in more detail than *"testing somethings on browsers"* and *"how i can understand what's going on?"*. Also, where does this *"some of them was reported malicious"* come from - do you use some external source of malicious IP or do you interpret yourself that something is malicious (and how)?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i edited that.

Comment: The contents of your `/etc/hosts` might help understanding why non-existing hostnames are resolved to Linode with your system.

Comment: DNS resolution of these meaningless addresses is either done on your computer or is forwarded from your computer. It might be DNS settings in the browser, on the router, at the ISP ... . To narrow down the cause please check if a) the problem is specific to this browser (i.e. check other browsers on same computer) or b) specific to this computer (check other computers in network) or if this is a network wide problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i checked all of them. its the same on other browsers. it isn't happening on other computers in the network, and the /etc/host does not resolve anything to specefic address and ip. (the computer is using Windows 10)

Comment: @SiGNoR: Does the affected machine use the same DNS server as the other unaffected machines in the network (see `ipconfig /all`). Does the problem vanish if you explicitly setup a different DNS server (like 8.8.8.8). Is there a proxy configured in the browser? Is there some antivirus, parental control or similar installed which might affect network traffic? What happens if you try HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich all machines use a local DNS, the problem does not solved while chaning dns servers. browsers have not any proxy configuration. no antivirus or other tools, just a DLP on machine.

Comment: What kind of network are you in? Who manages the DNS service? Does `nslookup signortest` give you the same result? Does `ipconfig` list a `DNS-Suffix` for your network adapter? `https://198.58.118.167/` serves a certificate for `*.mytrafficmanagement.com`

Comment: @SiGNoR: *"... just a DLP on machine. ..."* - DLP might be networking inspection too. Any details about this DLP? What happens if you disable it?

Comment: @xsrf `nslookup signortest` returns those malicious ips list. no ipconfig does not return DNS Suffix

Comment: @SteffenUllrich all details that i can say is that i can't disable the dlp.

Comment: @SiGNoR:  *"nslookup signortest returns those malicious ips list."* - then it is something with the DNS server used. If the result of nslookup is different on the other machines than it suggests that they use a different DNS server, which contradicts what you said before.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeserday after that, i checked another machine again. The problem was the VPN we used to connect elsewhere. After disconnecting, the DNS used by that VPN remained in my machine next to the organization's DNS, and after manually removing that DNS, the problem was resolved. That Dns is infected and we should check that. Thank you All. Steffen, xsrf and Esa.